# handling notification time with sensu

Tags: debian, sensu

I'm using Sensu for alerting. If anything goes wrong with any of service then it would trigger the alert and send us notification mail.

I've just come across one document where I can change the notification time outside business hours, [this](https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.24/reference/filters.html#example-handling-events-during-office-hours-only) is the document I was referring to.

I've created filter rule, `/etc/sensu/conf.d/filters/nine_to_fiver.json`

```
{
    "filters": {
      "nine_to_fiver": {
        "negate": false,
        "attributes": {
          "timestamp": "eval: [1,2,3,4,5].include?(Time.at(value).wday) && Time.at(value).hour.between?(9,17)"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

After making this change, I reloaded sensu-client deamon on client side but I'm still getting notification on mail ID. Is there anything wrong with filter rules ? Or Am I missing anything ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters must be applied on the Sensu Server, not the Sensu Client. Furthermore, the filter must reside server-side and the [handler must be configured](https://sensuapp.org/docs/1.1/reference/handlers.html#handler-attributes) to apply the filter.

Alternatively, you might be able to get a little fancy with the [when](https://sensuapp.org/docs/1.1/reference/filters.html#when-attributes) filter field.

Comment: thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Does "when" filter field also supposed to be configured on server-side ?

Comment: The "when" attributes can exist on any filter JSON configuration, so it would be within the `/etc/sensu/conf.d/filters/nine_to_fiver.json` that you originally showed (so, yes, server-side as well). I haven't tried it, but I imagine a filter that is exclusive (matched events are NOT handled), with just `eval: true` as the filter logic and a "when" block from 9 to 5, _might_ work. Your filter is directly from Sensu's documentation on how to filter for 9-to-5 though, so I'd stick with that.

Comment: just one question, can [sudue](https://sensuapp.org/docs/1.0/reference/checks.html#subdue-attributes) helps in this case for each check. And if so where it can be configured?

Comment: I imagine `subdue` and `when` are two similar constructs that have the same purpose. The difference being that `subdue` is configured in the check JSON (so client-side if using standalone checks) and `when` is configured in the handler JSON (always server-side).

Comment: ok got it. One more question, let's say I have one sensu server and 100 clients. But those 100 clients are divided based on environment. 50 clients are in production and 50 are in development. If I want to setup `subdue` only for development environment clients then how would I do that ? Can I setup global filter or do I have to set it per-check ?

Comment: can I contact you via email or something, please ?